# Coldfusion Docker is uninstalling modules on build

Tags: docker, coldfusion

I'm having issues with creating a useable docker container for a ColdFusion 2021 app. I can create the container, but everytime it is rebuilt I have to reinstall all of the modules (admin, search, etc.). This is an issue because the site that the container will be housed on will be rebuilding the container everyday.

The container is being built with docker-compose. I have tried using the installModule and importModule environmental variables, running the install command from the Dockerfile, building the container and creating a .car file to keep the settings, and disabling the secure mode using the environmental variables.

I have looked at the log, and all of the different methods used to install/import the modules are actually downloading and installing the modules. However, when the container first starts to spin up there's a section where the selected modules are installed (and the modules that are not installed are listed). That section is followed by the message that the coldfusion services are available, then it starts services, security, etc. and uninstalls (and removes) the modules. It then says that no modules are going to be installed because they are not present, and it gives the "services available" message again.

Somehow, it seems that one of the services is uninstalling and removing the module files, and none of the environmental variables (or even the setupscript) are affecting that process. I thought it might be an issue with the secure setup, but even with disabling that the problem persists. My main question is, what could be causing it to be uninstalled?

I was also looking for clarification on a couple of items:

a) all of the documentation I could find said that the .CAR file would be automatically loaded if it was in the /data folder (and in one spot it's referred to the image's /data folder). That would be at the top level with /opt and /app, right? I couldn't find an existing data folder anywhere.

b) Several of the logs and help functions mention a /docs folder, but I can't find it in the file directory. Would anyone happen to know where I can find them? It seems like that would be helpful for solving this.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the Adobe images provide a mechanism to automatically install modules every time the container rebuilds, but I recommend you look into the Ortus CommandBox-based images.  They have an environment variable for the cfpm packages you want installed and CFConfig which is much more robust than car files.

https://hub.docker.com/r/ortussolutions/commandbox/

FYI, I work for Ortus Solutions.

Comment: FWIW, I _don't_ work for Ortus and was gonna post the same thing.